# Transparent canvas on opencv video

Tags: python, opencv, canvas, tkinter

Is it possible to create transparent canvas in tkinter on opencv videos? OI want to draw some things on video in tkinter app.

I was trying with this code:

```
#Graphics window
mainWindow = tk.Tk()
mainWindow.configure(bg=lightBlue2)
mainWindow.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (maxWidth,maxHeight,0,0))
mainWindow.resizable(0,0)
# mainWindow.overrideredirect(1)
c = Canvas(mainWindow, width=640, height=480, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
c.create_line(0,240,640,240, fill='blue')
c.pack()
mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow)
mainFrame.place(x=20, y=20)                

#Capture video frames
lmain = tk.Label(mainFrame)
lmain.grid(row=0, column=0)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('foot.mp4')

def show_frame():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2image   = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

    img   = Image.fromarray(cv2image).resize((760, 400))
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, show_frame)

closeButton = Button(mainWindow, text = "CLOSE", font = fontButtons, bg =             white, width = 20, height= 1)
closeButton.configure(command= lambda: mainWindow.destroy())              
closeButton.place(x=270,y=430)  

show_frame()  #Display
mainWindow.mainloop()  #Starts GUI
```

but the canvas is always on bottom on video or at top of it

Comment: There are several questions about creating transparent windows in tkinter on this site. Have you read through them?

Comment: You can use `Canvas.create_image(...)` to show the opencv frame, then you can draw above the image with other canvas drawing functions.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible in tkinter to make a canvas transparent but it is possible to make youre winodw transparent. You need to do something else